# XML instance has wrong parent element

Tags: xml

I am just starting to learn XML but I keep getting this error on the coursebook I am learning from:

`The element at this point in your instance has the wrong parent element. Most likely it is next to rather than inside the parent tag.`

This is how my code is structured

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infoAssets>
<companyName></companyName>
    <products>
     <product/> <title/>  <description/><specification/>
    </products>
    <services>
        <service/>
        <title/>
        <description/>
    </services>    
</infoAssets>
```

I don't understand where the child is outside of the parent.

Comment: The document is valid, so the error message will be about what the course expects, not the document itself. I would *guess* that it is complaining about the `<product/>` element being self-closed, making the elements after it siblings, not children, but the wording of your question doesn't specify. What is the course expecting?

Comment: Its saying that the there is an element outside the parent element. Which is where I am confused because it seems everything is on the parent

Answer (score 0):

I thing that problem is structure of XML file not validation.
`<title>`, `<description>` and `<specification>` at `<products>` and `<services>` are not included at right node, because parent nodes `<product>` and `<service>` are empty because `<product/>` and `<service/>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infoAssets>
    <companyName></companyName>    
</infoAssets>
<products>
    <product>
        <title/>
        <description/>
        <specification/>
    </product>
</products>
<services>
    <service>
        <title/>
        <description/>
    </service>
</services>
```